# What is the SOURCEsourceXXX file in firefox debugger and where is it?

Tags: jsp, web, firefox

I was trying to find some code in website by chrome debugger, but I couldn't find it using global search(<kbd>ctrl + shift + F</kbd>). So I opened firefox debugger and did the same thing. Then, I saw it exist in `SOURCEsourceXXX` (`XXX` is number) file. But I couldn't find this file in source tab and neither network tab. 
What is this file and where can I find this file?